# Why my sed command works separetly but doesn't in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

this is my first post in Stackoverflow. I have an issue with executing sed command in the script while same command works fine separetly.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=file
sensitive="censored"

while IFS=  read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == *"Memory Region Size"* ]];
        then
                server_name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $11}')
                echo "$line"  >> test
        elif [[ $(echo "$line" | wc -w) == 4 ]];
        then
                echo "$line" | awk '$4="censored"' >> test
        else
                echo "$line" >> test
        fi
done < $filename

sed -i "s/${server_name}/${sensitive}/g" test
echo $server_name
echo $sensitive
```

I want to censor file with replacing server_name with "censored". This is output I am taking:

```
$ ./log_censor.sh 
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
ABC-123 
censored
```

The same command it one-line command works fine for me:

```
$ cat file1
My server is ABC-123

$ server_name="ABC-123";sensitive="censored";sed -i "s/${server_name}/${sensitive}/g" file1

$ cat file1
My server is censored
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please add `set -x` on top of you script and post the output then.

Comment: Is it fine to post only last lines of the output since this is a prod file?
```
++ read -r line
++ sed -i 's/ABC-123/censored/g' test
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
++ echo 'ABC-123'
ABC-123
++ echo censored
censored
```

Comment: I suspect the file contains CRLF newlines. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this command. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Okay, so - the text file comes from AIX but I run my script and try to censor this file on RHEL and on Windows VS Code with GIt installed. Both with same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing bash and awk and sed seems unnecessary. Do it all with one language, awk for example.

```
# usage: awk -f this_script.awk file file > test

BEGIN {sensitive = "censored"}

NR == FNR && /Memory Region Size/ {server_name = $11}
NR == FNR {next}

NF == 4 {$4 = sensitive}
{
    gsub(server_name, sensitive)
    print
}
```